# Why is there a man entry in /etc/passwd

Tags: users

I've noticed that there is an entry for the man user in my `/etc/passwd` file. What is the purpose of this user?

```
man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/bin/sh
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`man` (the command, not the user) is a help application. Applications provide man pages in their packages but `man` needs to know where they are and also what help they provide. To speed things up — so `man` isn't search the whole filesystem when you type `man <command>` — these man pages are indexed into a database by a command called `mandb`.

In Ubuntu `mandb` stores indexes in a GNU gdbm database at `/var/cache/man/index.db` (and a few language specific versions in the same directory). This is a key-value hashing database not dissimilar to memcache, or a hundred other implementations on similar ideas. It's binary, light and fast. I'll throw in an example of how to play with it at the end.

This indexing is scheduled to run daily in Ubuntu by `/etc/cron.daily/man-db`. The whole script runs as root and does some cleaning up first but right at the end we see `mandb` being run as the `man` user:

```
# --pidfile /dev/null so it always starts; mandb isn't really a daemon,
# but we want to start it like one.
start-stop-daemon --start --pidfile /dev/null \
                  --startas /usr/bin/mandb --oknodo --chuid man \
                  $iosched_idle \
                  -- --no-purge --quiet
```

It's not changing group, which is why all the group ownerships in `/var/cache/man` are still root.

**But why does `mandb` run as a different user at all?** It could (probably) run just as well as `root` but it's *processing input* from a variety of sources (look at `manpath`). Running as its own user insulates the system from the process blowing up —or worse— being exploited by malformed, corrupted or malicious man pages.

The worst that could happen would only affect the `man` pages index. Boo hoo. You can confirm that with something like:

```
sudo -u man find / -writable 2>/dev/null
```

And you can use that approach to see how much damage any user could wreak on a system. It's a good idea to audit your file permissions (I just found out that any user could delete my entire music collection, for example).

---

You can peek at the database with `accessdb`. Here are a few random records:

```
$ accessdb | shuf -n3
fpurge -> "- 3 3 1380819168 A - - gz purge a stream"
fcgetlangs -> "FcGetLangs 3 3 1402007131 A - - gz Get list of languages"
ipython -> "- 1 1 1393443907 A - - gz Tools for Interactive Computing in Python."
```

Though not entirely clear from the above, there are actually tab-separated fields in there:

```
<name> -> <ext> <sec> <mtime> <ID> <ref> <comp> <whatis>
```

You can read more about the actual field contents in [the technical manual](http://www.botik.ru/doc/man-db/man-db-manual.html#toc40).

Comment: Maybe you could add an explanation of why this service (and many others) have their own user, and are not just run as root or something?

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy Thorough enough?

Comment: That's excellent!