# Why such long list of users and groups in my system?

Tags: users, groups

On my laptop `$ cat /etc/passwd | wc -l` results `42`!
And `cat /etc/group | wc -l` results `70`!!

The only user of my laptop is myself and there is only an extra user named "guest". But why such large number of users and groups are available?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/q/512834/158442, http://askubuntu.com/q/329714/158442 and extrapolate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short: privilege separation. Many different services and subsystems have their own user and group. Doing so enables fine tuning of the access rights for each user. Such a system also serves to enhance security. For example, if an intruder, or app/script with malicious code in it, makes it to be recognized as a user with root privileges, the entire system could be compromised.